# Default windows hidden files systems

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-registry, system-reserved-partition, named-pipe

During my learning of how named pipes works inside Windows, I've found this explanation :

> Every pipe is placed in the root directory of the named pipe
> filesystem (NPFS), mounted under the special path \.\pipe\

It's not the first time I did not understand how windows know the location of the files inside the filesystem.

For example when looking for a registry entry with powershell :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion'
```

When looking for hidden partitions inside windows the only one I've found is **System Reserved** and no more details.

Is the **named pipe filesystem (NPFS)** stored in this partition?

Is there a way to lookup all the files contained in that partition?

Where are located the mount points of theses partitions inside the C:\ partition?

And the most important of all my questions, is there a way to know all the windows special file paths like `HKLM:\` or `\\.\pipe\`?

Comment: you can get a list of all the pipes like this in powershell `(get-childitem \\.\pipe\).FullName` You can remove the .fullname from the end to get the contents of each pipe directory

Comment: `Is the named pipe filesystem (NPFS) stored in this partition` .. no, you are referring to a physical partition in an actual hardware device.  Named pipes are virtual.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to lookup all the files contained in that partition?

Use the following PowerShell command:

> ```
> [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\\pipe\\")
> ```

Source: [How can I get a list of all open named pipes in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066420/3536342), answer by [Andrew Shepherd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25216/andrew-shepherd)

---

#### Is there a way to know all the windows special file paths like HKLM:\ or \.\pipe?

These are known as UNC file paths ([File path formats on Windows systems | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats)). There can be no definitive list as such paths can, for example, include server names - we cannot knoiw in advance what the names are.